# With dplyr, using inner_join has no Where condition?

Tags: r, inner-join, dplyr

If I'm using `inner_join` in `dplyr`, I can do this:

```
inner_join(x, y, by = ID)
```

but how can I do this?

```
inner_join(x, y, by = ID, ID>5)
```

...where `ID>5` is a condition on the join?

From what I see on the documentation, this isn't directly possible with `inner_join`. I'd like to think I could pipe the output and maybe use `filter` but this wouldn't avoid a potentially expensive operation.  Is there any solution to this?

Comment: `this wouldn't avoid a potentially expensive operation` Why not use `filter` first, then? `x %>% inner_join(y, by = ID)`

Comment: @David Robinson, what if the `where` condition is along the lines of `x.score = y.score`? Using `ID>5`, in retrospect, was kinda silly, because it looks at a constant.

Comment: maybe `inner_join(x[x$ID>5], y[y$ID>5], by=ID)`

Comment: @MattO'Brien Then you'd join on both: `x %>% inner_join(y, by = c("ID", "score"))`

Comment: @DavidRobinson   :)  Hard to pull a fast one on you! OK, how about `x.score > y.score`? This example demonstrates the usefulness of a `where` condition, no?

Comment: @MattO'Brien Then you'd need to filter afterwards. You couldn't save an expensive operation by combining the two steps; inner join would still have to join based on the specified columns, then evaluate your condition on the ones it joined

Comment: ...and that pre-filter is fundamentally the same as @PierreLafortune's answer. I see. Thanks.